# Can't Call a UIView from inside a Facebook IOS Request

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, ios6

I have the following setup in IOS6 to connect to Facebook through my app.

```
self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [self.accountStore
                                      accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

// Specify App ID and permissions
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
                          ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                          };

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                      options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
                                          if (granted) {
                                              NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore
                                                                   accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
                                              self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                              NSLog(@"Logged In :: %@",self.facebookAccount);

                                              [self uploadVideo];

                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              NSLog(@"Logged In Fail");
                                          }
                                      }];
```

The problem is that I want to provide some feedback in the form of a UIAlertView where the else statement is. When I add the following the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Unable To Connect With Facebook"
                      message: @"xxxxxxxxxxxxx."
                      delegate: nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

If I just call a method with no alert view in then that seems to work fine. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the completion block is on the main thread?

Try to wrap your alert view code in a dispatch to the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

});
```

Comment: Tried wrapping it around it with no luck.

Comment: Ok, an update to the above. If you place the dispatch_async inside the completion handler then it fails. If however you place the dispatch_async inside a separate method and then call that from the completion handler then it works. Thanks